# Есть ли способ выключить функцию в JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ли способ выключить функцию на время использование другой?

У меня есть две функции. Первая отвечает за то, что при скролле вниз у навигации меняются активные кнопки.
Вторая отвечает за быстрый переход по навигации

Вопрос: можно ли при использовании второй "выключить" использовании первой?

Спасибо

Comment: В такой формулировке - нет, `JS` исполняется одним потоком (верно для браузеров).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В такой формулировке - нет, JS исполняется одним потоком (верно для браузеров).
Но можно обойтись флагом:

```js
let flag = true,
    log  = null;

function firstFn(){
  // Если флаг равен false, происходит выход
  if(!flag)
    return;
  
  log.innerHTML = `Первая функция работает: ${Math.random()}!`;
}

function secondFn(){
  // При старте, блокируем флаг
  flag = false;
  
  new Promise((a, d) => {
    log.innerHTML = `Пока первая функция не работает, проверь.`;
    setTimeout(a, 3000);
  }).then(() => {
    // Как только какой-то долгий процесс закончился, разблокируем флаг
    flag = true;
    log.innerHTML = `Первая функция вновь в строю, проверь.`;
  });
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.querySelector('#f').addEventListener('click', firstFn);
  document.querySelector('#s').addEventListener('click', secondFn);
  
  log = document.querySelector('#log');
});
```

```html
<input type='button' id='f' value='Выполни меня полностью!' /> | <input type='button' id='s' value='Я долгая функция, пока я работаю, первая не будет работать!' /><br />

<span id='log'></span>
```

Comment: тут скорее не флагом а промисом, без него флаг безполезен

Comment: @Grundy, в данном примере - да, но это искусственная задержка, у ТС может быть другая (что-то там про скролл - пока анимация не закончится, флаг блокирует выполнение).

Answer (score 0):

Яваскрипт - однопоточен, то есть одновременно может выполняться только одна функция.

Comment: Но у меня то две выполняются

Comment: Одна - смотри на  scrollTop() и меняет класс в соответствии с дистанцией, а другая по клику

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, по очереди - да. Как только процесс входит в фазу бездействия, только тогда выполняются запланированные операции, не раньше.

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, добавьте в любую свою функцию бесконечный цикл и вы увидите, что пока она выполняется больше **ничего** не будет выполняться